# How to execute N inserts in mysql and in a "all or nothing " mode

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions, innodb

I need to make N inserts into a bunch of tables but if any of them fails I want all of the inserts to be rolled.

I am using MySql 8.0 and InnoDB, I have spent a lot of time trying to make it work out and I have read that I should be using transactions to achieve that but it isn't working how I would like and I don't know how to fix it.

This is the definition of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Example` (
  `A` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `ID` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);
```

the table only contains the record ("abc", 1)

So I execute

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO `Example` (`A`, `ID`) VALUES ("abd", 2);
INSERT INTO `Example` (`A`, `ID`) VALUES ("abc", 1);
COMMIT;
```

after the transaction  ("abd", 2) is added to the table.
I would expect to not have any change on the table since the second insert that is inside the transaction fails

Comment: If there's an error you should use `ROLLBACK;` instead of `COMMIT;`

Comment: How are you executing the queries?

Comment: But how can I know if an error occured?

Comment: If you're executing the queries by hand, you should see an error message. If you're doing it from a programming language, it should provide a way to test the success of queries.

Comment: I am executing them via Mysql workbench, but how can I setup some behavior like "if it fails rollback otherwise go on"?

Comment: You can't put conditionals in Workbench, you have to do it the checks by hand. You can put the code in a stored procedure, it can check for errors.

Comment: You're not going to be using Workbench for your real application, are you? Won't it be written using a programming language?

Comment: I would like this query to be a simple string so I can put it inside a servlet where it takes attributes from a form, how can I achieve this? My real problem is that I have a table "song" and a table "Singer" , a song must be sung by at least one singer but could also be many. In my form the user puts the info of the song and of one of its singers and then it should insert data into song and the table "singing" , those should be two inserts that should act in a all or nothing way since there can't exist a song that has no singer , fixing the easier example on table "example" would help a lot

Comment: Barmar's comment is most appropriate.  The transaction should include error handling and if you want the transaction to fail if any portion of the batch is not successful then it should ROLLBACK on error.

Answer (score 0):

Your **transaction demarcation layer** is wrong. You are executing `COMMIT` regardless of the 3rd statement suceeding or failing (it fails).

This is probably due to the statements being executed in the command line, one after another, without considering error conditions.

Transaction APIs such as Spring, JTA, etc. would "doom" the transaction when the 3rd statement fails, and would never honor a commit after that. They would translate the commit to a rollback instead.

For example in Spring you **demarcate** transactions by marking a method with the `@Transactional` annotation. You never execute a commit or a rollback programatically; Spring does it for you when the method finishes. In this case any `RuntimeException` thrown by the method will doom the transaction and Spring will rollback when the method finishes its execution. Otherwise, it will commit the transaction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have never used spring, I know java and I am just starting to use servlet and jsp, could you provide me an example of how you would solve my problem?